# how to limit the number of emails(azure email communication) to send, c#?

Tags: c#, email, azure-communication-services

I'm working in a console application that reads a record from the database and sends an email using Azure Email Communication accordingly.

| SEID | ShouldEmailBeSent | HasEmailBeenSent | EmailSentTime | NextActionBy | NextActionByUser |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | Null | S22 | ManagerUser |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | Null | CloudTeam | TechUser |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | Null | AITeam | TechUser |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | Null | CloudTeam | TechUser |

this is the record in my database table "WorkExtended".

What I Did :

I have 2 categories in NextActionByUser column "ManagerUser" and "TechUser" If ShouldEmailBeSent = 1, then it checks the NextActionByUser ="ManagerUser", then it checks  NextActionBy for Manager userid, and with that userid it gets the email id of manager from another table(UserDetails) then an email will be sent. If NextActionByUser ="TechUser"(TechUser has many teams), NextActionBy ="check the TeamName" and each Team has 3 to 4 members, I do not want to send 3 to 4 emails for Each SEID, So I grouped the SEID which shares the same NextActionBy(Team), in that way it will only send 3 emails for SEID which shares the same Team.

```
int maxEmailsToSend = 4;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(dbConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            string query = "SELECT SEID, ShouldEmailBeSent,NextActionBy,NextActionByUser FROM WorkExtended " + "WHERE ShouldEmailBeSent = 'True' AND HasEmailBeenSent = 'False' AND EmailSentTime IS NULL ";
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    Dictionary<string, List<int>> seidsByTeam = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
                    int emailsSentCount = 0;
                    while (reader.Read() && emailsSentCount< maxEmailsToSend)
                    {

                        int seid = Convert.ToInt32(reader["SEID"]);
                        bool shouldemailbesent = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["ShouldEmailBeSent"]);
                        string nextActionByUser = reader["NextActionByUser"].ToString();


                        if (shouldemailbesent)
                        {
                            if (nextActionByUser == "TechUser")
                            {
                                string teamName = GetTeamNameFromNextActionBy(connection, nextActionByUser, seid);
                                if (!seidsByTeam.ContainsKey(teamName))
                                {
                                    seidsByTeam[teamName] = new List<int>();
                                }
                                seidsByTeam[teamName].Add(seid);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                string managerId = GetManagerUserIdFromNextActionBy(connection, nextActionByUser, seid);
                                string managerEmail = GetEmailForManagerUser(connection, managerId);
                                if (emailsSentCount < maxEmailsToSend)
                                {
                                    await SendEmailToRecipient(seid, managerEmail);
                                    emailsSentCount++;
                                    string updateQuery = "UPDATE WorkExtended SET HasEmailBeenSent = 'True', EmailSentTime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE SEID = @SEID";

                                    using (SqlCommand updateCommand = new SqlCommand(updateQuery, connection))
                                    {
                                        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SEID", seid);
                                        updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                        Console.WriteLine("Updated SEID: " + seid);
                                    }
                                }                                   
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    foreach (var teamEntry in seidsByTeam)
                    {
                        string teamName = teamEntry.Key;
                        List<int> seidsForTeam = teamEntry.Value;
                        List<string> techUserEmails = GetEmailsForTechUsers(connection, teamName);
                        if (emailsSentCount < maxEmailsToSend)
                        {
                            int remainingEmails = maxEmailsToSend - emailsSentCount;
                            int emailsToSendForTeam = Math.Min(remainingEmails, seidsForTeam.Count);

                            if (emailsToSendForTeam > 0)
                            {
                                await SendGroupEmail(seidsForTeam.GetRange(0, emailsToSendForTeam), techUserEmails);
                                emailsSentCount += emailsToSendForTeam;
                            }
                            string updateQuery = "UPDATE WorkExtended SET HasEmailBeenSent = 'True', EmailSentTime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE SEID = @SEIDs";

                            using (SqlCommand updateCommand = new SqlCommand(updateQuery, connection))
                            {
                                updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SEIDs", string.Join(",", seidsForTeam.GetRange(0, emailsToSendForTeam)));
                                updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                Console.WriteLine($"Updated SEIDs: {string.Join(", ", seidsForTeam.GetRange(0, emailsToSendForTeam))}");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
```

What I want is :

I want to limit the number of emails sent. If I set maxEmailsToSend = 4 means, it has to only send 4, not more than that. for eg: according to my database, it sends the email for SEID 1 and updates the database HasEmailBeenSent = 1,EmailSentTime = "date of email send". Now only 3 email remains, then it checks the remaining record, groups my SEID 2 and 4 sends the email to the 3 members of CloudTeam, and updates my database.
Now the email limit is reached and it should not send emails. But the problem is it also sent emails for SEID 3. I want something like, if the limit is reached it should not send emails. Even when it has 1 more email remains within its limit, but the next record(seid) has a team where it has to send mail to 3 members, it should not send. I tried Something in my code but I couldn't figure out how to achieve this exactly.

Thanks.

Comment: Show us the "something you tried". Stack Overflow doesn't exist to write your code for you, but to help you make what you've written work.

Comment: Hi, I know that Stack Overflow doesn't exist to write code for me or anyone, I also know that it helps coders to get better. I have also posted the code, that's what I tried and it is working but it's not satisfying my condition. I tried different ways but still, I couldn't figure out what I was missing. I'm a beginner coder, I'm not a pro like you all. That's why I'm asking for help. Sorry, if I made any mistakes.